# Apache httpd got 403 forbidden on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf, macos-high-sierra

I tried to install Apache HTTPD via Homebrew with `brew install apache2`, it worked well with default configuration http://localhost:8080
However, once I added more virtual host, to another folder (actually just clone the www folder to new one), and then tried to access to that new virtual host, I got 403 Forbidden error.

I don't think there was any wrong configuration, because it worked well with Apache2 on Ubuntu, but don't know why it's broken on MacOS, even I changed permission to 777 for that new www folder

Thanks

Comment: please, post here configuration of your virtual hosts

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same wall, so I'd like to share my experience and hope it can help.

1. First of all, look at the error message in the log file that you specified for your virtual host.
2. If you see something like:

   [authz_core:error] [pid 57233] [client 127.0.0.1:55693] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/local/www/your_vhost/

which indicates the module `authz_core` cause the forbidden. In this case, add `Require all granted` in your VirtualHost block can solve the problem.

3. There are different modules can cause the same problem, so you'd better to see the message in the log first.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache2 error log helped me solved the mystery. It turned out that 127.0.0.1 is pointed to a VH with folder location in where there is no index.html. I thought it was pointing to my Docroot as in the case of the localhost.